# Second-order ODE dopri5 python UserWarning: larger nmax

Tags: python, scipy, ode, user-warning

For a second-order ODE (dopri5 method in python) the code below always results in an error: `C:\Users\MY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py:1019: UserWarning: dopri5: larger nmax is needed
  self.messages.get(idid, 'Unexpected idid=%s' % idid))`. I've changed the parameters but nothing seems to help. Even setting `nsteps=100000` doesn't work. Is there any other way to solve this instead of just increasing`nsteps`?

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np

def fun(t, y):
    return np.array([y[1], -3/t*y[1] + 7/(t**6)*y[0]])

yinit = np.array([0.01, 0.2])

dt = 0.01
t_stop = 2

solver = ode(fun).set_integrator('dopri5', nsteps=100000).set_initial_value(yinit)
solver.t = 0.001
t_RK4_sci = [0]
x_RK4_sci = [yinit]
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t_stop:
    solver.integrate(solver.t+dt, step=True)
    t_RK4_sci.append(solver.t)
    x_RK4_sci.append(solver.y)
t_RK4_sci = np.array(t_RK4_sci)
x_RK4_sci = np.array(x_RK4_sci)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a

```
print t,y
```

as first line in `fun` to see that your solution is rapidly exploding while employing very small step sizes. The last lines of that log are

```
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204893e+289   6.79981963e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204893e+289   6.79981963e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204893e+289   6.79981964e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204893e+289   6.79981964e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204897e+289   6.79981974e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204899e+289               inf]
0.00100025397168 [ inf  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204894e+289   6.79981966e+298]
0.00100025397168 [  2.57204894e+289               inf]
0.00100025397168 [ inf  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
0.00100025397168 [ nan  nan]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate
/_ode.py:1018: UserWarning: dopri5: step size becomes too small
  self.messages.get(idid, 'Unexpected idid=%s' % idid))
```

---

To see the mathematical side of it observe that the initial Lipschitz constant is somewhere at `L=1e+18`.

- Useful step sizes for numerical integration have to observe `L*dt < 10`, probably a smaller upper bound, to stay inside the region of A-stability for explicit methods.
- The magnification rate from local to global error is `(exp(L*T)-1)`, where `T` is the length of the integration interval. This means that meaningful results can only be expected for, optimistically, `L*T < 50`, which gives `T<5e-17`.

Under those theoretical restrictions, the dopri5 integrator proves as quite robust in practice since it bails out only at `T=2.5e-7`.

---

Perturbation to the Euler form

```
t²·y'' + 3t·y' - 7/t0^4·y = 0
```

gives initial growth in the range of

```
(t/t0) ^ 3e6
```

and since the largest double is around `10^300` the numerical range gets exceeded at around

```
t/t0 = 10 ^ 1e-4 = 1.00023028502  or t=0.00100023028502
```

which is the closest to where the numerical integration bails out and thus probably the true reason. (Better bounds give `10^(308/2.6e6)=1.00027280498`.)

---

### Summary

Not only has this differential equation an exceedingly large Lipschitz constant and is thus ill-behaved or stiff, also the exact solution, as far as the approximation by an Euler equation can tell, grows so fast to exceed the `double` range at the time where the numerical integration breaks down. That is, even a better method like an implicit integrator will not give better results.